# jQuery only applies to the first elements on every page

Tags: jquery, toggle, element

I have a bunch of html elements with the same ids and classes. I have added a jQuery toggling function to these classes and ids, but it only works properly on the 1st samples on every page. How do I fix it?

Comment: You cannot have more one element with the same ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you are having **`SAME IDs`**. Every element **SHOULD** have a different **ID**. Although they can share same class.

If multiple elements have same ID then you will of course see unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have same id on more than one element, ids should be unique through out you page. Make it unique, should help.
Classes can be duplicated.

Comment: wow thanks a lot guys!! I am completely self-trained, however I still cannot believe how I never came over this one... sounds very basic lol. thanks a lot again! take care